# How to use greater than symbol in html with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am quite new to angular 2 . I am trying to use 2 different css based on some conditions on based on mathematical operations applied on someid. If id > 10 then css 1 should get applied else css 2.
But it is throwing template parsing error.

html file

```
 <ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">

 <span [ngClass]= "{{hero.id}}>10'?'css-Fail':'css-Paas'"> {{hero.name}}****This line is throwing error****
 </span>
```

css file

```
.css-Fail {
background-color:coral;
 }
 .css-Green{
background-color:green;
   }
```

Comment: `ngClass` takes an *object*, `{ 'css-Fail': hero.id > 10, 'css-Pass': hero.id >= 10 }`. Maybe read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngClass)? Also that should probably be *"Pass"*, not  *"Paas"*, or maybe even *"Green"* to, you know, *actually match* your CSS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<ul class="heroes"><li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)"> <span [ngClass]= "hero.id>10?'css-Fail':'css-Paas'"> {{hero.name}}
```

it will work if you remove {{ }}

Answer (score 0):

This should work --

`[ngClass]="{'css-Green': hero.id>10, 'css-Fail': hero.id>=10 }"`